# Eclipse: getting IO exception when stepping through perl code

Tags: eclipse, perl

I'd like to debug a perl program in Eclipse, but every time I open the debugger, and press the step-over button (or the step into button for that matter), I get a Dialog box saying "PerlDebugJob has encountered a problem".   It then gives the following:

```
An IOException occurred while executing debugger command
could not match re.IP_POS in {recv() is deprecated on :utf8 handles. This will be a fatal error in Perl 5.30 at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Socket.pm line 304.
 at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Socket.pm line 304.
    IO::Socket::recv(IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x33d6238), "", 2048) called at C:/Users/John/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.epic.debug/perl5db.pl line 7358
    DB::readline("  DB<16> ") called at C:/Users/John/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.epic.debug/perl5db.pl line 1858
    DB::_DB__read_next_cmd(undef) called at C:/Users/John/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.epic.debug/perl5db.pl line 2786
    DB::DB called at F:/Shared/John/Java/unifdef+.0.2.1/test.pl line 4
main::(F:/Shared/John/Java/unifdef+.0.2.1/test.pl:4):
4:  my $rundir = "script\/";}
```

I am running Eclipse Neon.3, and I just installed Padwalker through a `cpan padwalker` command on  my DOS prompt.  My perl is 5.26.0.   Is there anything else I have to do?  (I tried a more recent version of Eclipse with the same results).

The first few lines of the program I am trying to debug are:

```
use File::Compare;
my $result;
my $rundir = "script\/";
```

Comment: It looks like EPIC is getting a deprecation warnings (`recv() is deprecated on :utf8 handles.`) from `perl` where none was expected. Downgrading `perl` would sidestep the issue till it's fixed in EPIC.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the program you are trying to debug. You should get the same error from the program `1;`.